# Retain Dynamic dropdown values

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have 3 dyanmically generated dropdowns in this aspx page. The 2nd and 3rd one are populated as per the selected value of the first one (I've the code for creating the 2nd and 3rd dropdown in 1st one's selectedindexchanged event)

How do I write the code in a such a way that when I traverse back to the page, the dynamic dropdowns retain their selected values?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that what you mean when you say that you "traverse back" to the page is that you navigate to a different page on the site and come back to this page that it's dropdown values will be filled in with what the user selected.

Remember that HTTP is an inherintly statless protocol in that it won't remember data in between postback to the servers. In order to overcome this limitation ASP.NET and other web frameworks use various ways of saving data between request. Currently you are relying on "ViewState" that is stored within the page as a hidden variable called __VIEWSTATE (look at the page source sometime to get an idea of what field looks like) this scope of this hidden variable is when the page first gets loaded and everytime you do a postback to the same page. From your description you probably need a longer term persistance called SessionState or Cookies that will store values for a particular Session.

Here is a link from MSDN that contains interesting information regarding all the possible ways of saving state in an ASP.NET application. Let me know if you've got any other questions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx

--EDIT--
Here's a link to the MSDN article on Session State. My recommendation is to be careful with Session state and only store things that are absolutely required. Also I'd recommend you have a Class that contains the a bunch of constant for the Session Keys. It's easier to manage

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

ie instead of

```
string value = Session["Key"];


//Create a class SessionKeys
Class SessionKeys{
    public const string SESSION_KEY = "Key"
}


//Now that string is strongly typed and you don't have to worry about misspelling it

string value = Sesssion[SessionKeys.SESSION_KEY];
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for! Could you somehow provide an example as to how to do this? I doubt I'd get the code for this specific scenario elsewhere, thus saving time! Thanks!

Comment: And the 2 dropdowns disappear when I navigate back because I've initialized them in first dropdown's selectedindexchanged event.Is there any other possible way to do this?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind that when working with ASP.NET is the concept of "page lifecycle". I really can't stress that enough. Once you grok that concept everything becomes possible. It's  especially important if you will want to be making dynamic controls in the code behide. The reason that your dropdowns aren't created is that the IndexChanged event isn't fired every time the page is loaded. Try this as an exercise. Add a button to the page, select something with the dropdown that adds the other two dropdowns and then click the button. The dynamically created dropdowns should go away.

Comment: Useful links  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx. Can you explain why the dropdowns disappear?